# Generate same Path aliases for multi languages

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have a content type **Products**. A pattern is defined via the Pathauto module for **product** CT. but my issue is that when I translate an entry/node it generates a translated path alias for Urdu in Roman-English(Urdu in English alphabet) But the spellings of that path are meaningless. When I uncheck *"Transliterate prior to creating alias"* It generates the aliases in pure Urdu which is unacceptable in my case.
My proposed solution is to have the same path aliases for both languages with a "UR" Prefix in URL for Urdu.
E.g
English: example.com/product/windows-10-licence
Urdu: example.com/**ur**/product/windows-10-licence
I have tried everything using the Pathauto module but was unsuccessful. How I can regenerate and replace all Urdu path aliases with English path aliases. I am looking for a programmatic ly solution.